# How to create follower relationships using Eloquent and Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So, I'm trying to create a relationship where users can follow other users or follow categories. 
My intuition says that what I've done so far is not the right way of doing things. I'm especially confounded by how to create the *follower* - *followee* relationship.

**TABLES:**

Users

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('first_name');
        });
    }
```

Categories

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('category');
        });
    }
```

Follows

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('follows', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('follower_id');
            $table->integer('followee_id')->nullable();
            $table->integer('category_id')->nullable();
        });
    }
```

**MODELS:**

User

```
class User extends Model implements Authenticatable 
{

    public function follows()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Follow');
    }
}
```

Category

```
class Category extends Model
{

    public function follows()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Follow');
    }
}
```

Follow

```
class Follow extends Model
{
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function source()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your scenario, it is recommended that you use `Polymorphic Many To Many` relationship.

**Schema:**

```
users
    id - integer
    ...

categories
    id - integer
    ...

followables
    user_id - integer
    followable_id - integer
    followable_type - string
```

**Models:**

User:

```
public function followers()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(User::class, 'followables');
}
public function following()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(User::class, 'followables');
}
```

Category:

```
public function followers()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(User::class, 'followables');
}
```

Then you can create the relationship like:

When following an User:

`$user->followers()->create(['user_id' => 12])`

When following a Category:

`$category->followers()->create(['user_id' => 25])`

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did try this but it seemed like it tried to save all the data to the **users** table instead of **followables** table.

Anyway I did try to use your suggestion to solve it but I can't figure it out. There were so much new information so I created a new thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42205928/how-to-create-follower-relationships-using-polymorphic-many-to-many-relationship/42206344#42206344