# How to create follower relationships using Polymorphic Many to Many relationships with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, polymorphic-associations

Okay, so I'm trying to create a relationship where users can follow other users or follow categories. I got a recommendation to use [Polomorpic Many to Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations) relationships. Right now I'm trying to create a *follower - followee* relationship but I can't wrap my head around how to set up the models and the controller.

**TABLES**

Users

```
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('first_name');
        });
```

Categories

```
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('category');
        });
```

Followables

```
        Schema::create('followables', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('followable_id');
            $table->string('followable_type');
        });
```

**MODELS**

User

```
class User extends Model implements Authenticatable 
{

    public function followers()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Followable', 'followable');
    }

    public function following()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Followable', 'followable');
    }

    //Use to get id from Auth facade
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Followable

```
class Followable extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['user_id'];

    public function followable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

}
```

The Category model follower relationship does not exist yet so I will leave that one out for now.

**CONTROLLER**

FollowableController

```
class FollowableController extends Controller
{

    public function followUser($followable_id){

        $user_id = Auth::user()->getId();
        $followee = User::find($followable_id);
        $followee->followers()->create(['user_id' => $user_id]);


        return redirect()->route('get.user', ['user_id' => $followable_id]);
    }

}
```

To be honest I'm a bit confused by the code I've created. It's been some copy and pasting without understanding 100 % of what I do. Anyways, this will create *two* records in the database looking like this:

Followable

```
-------------------------------------------------
|Id | user_id | followable_id | followable_type |
-------------------------------------------------
|22  | 4       | NULL          | NULL            |
-------------------------------------------------
|23  | 0       | 22            | App\User        |
-------------------------------------------------
```

The followable_id is *wrong* and seems to use the Id which is created in the Followable table instead of the user_id from the User table.

So, how to solve so that there is **only one record being saved** to the database with the **right followable_id**?

Comment: Did you get this fixed?

Comment: I guess this time you have to add it explicitly to the `follower()` relationship function in the User model i.e `return $this->morphMany('App\Followable', 'followable', null, 'followable_id');`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using the wrong method. I did something like that following Laravel's doc example, and `morphMany()` was sufficient, since your `User` can have many followers, which are themselves `user` so you can have:

`User` model:

```
public function followers()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Followable', 'followable');
}
```

Then you can set the user_id from the controller (but don't forget to add it to fillable).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Nothing gets saved to the database when I try this one. Is there anything more I should change?

Comment: @AdamDedanga, are you sure you have the right field as foreign key to these tables. And were you able to find a solution to it?